# Hacer zoom a imagen sin que se corte

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando hacer zoom a una imagen cuando se presiona un botón. Lo intento hacer con la propiedad `transform:scale();` de CSS y con JavaScript.

El problema es que cuando se realiza el zoom, la imagen se corta, intenté agregar la propiedad `overflow:auto;` al elemento "padre" sin obtener resultados positivos.

¿Alguna idea de como puedo realizar esta acción?

Les dejo un ejemplo para que puedan ver lo que esta pasando.

```js
btnZoomIn = document.querySelector("#zoom-in");
      img = document.querySelector("#my-image");
      scale = 1;

      btnZoomIn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        scale += 0.5;

        img.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
      });
```

```css
.container-img {
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
      .controls {
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="controls">
      <button id="zoom-in">ZOOM-IN</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-img">
      <img id="my-image" src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/ilustracion-icono-vector-dibujos-animados-astronauta-montando-cohete-concepto-icono-tecnologia-ciencia-aislado-vector-premium-estilo-dibujos-animados-plana_138676-3469.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tendrías que asignarle el valor `overflow:visible`, no auto. Esto solucionaría lo del corte de la imagen, pero te llevaría al problema de que el botón quedaría sepultado bajo la imagen, al hacer zoom. Se solucionaría añadiendo al botón un `position:relative` (necesario para poder asignarle un z-index), y un `z-index: 1`, por ejemplo.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcional:

```js
btnZoomIn = document.querySelector("#zoom-in");
      img = document.querySelector("#my-image");
      scale = 1;

      btnZoomIn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        scale += 0.5;

        img.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
      });
```

```css
.container-img {
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: visible;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
      .controls {
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 1;
      }
```

```html
<div class="controls">
      <button id="zoom-in">ZOOM-IN</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-img">
      <img id="my-image" src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/ilustracion-icono-vector-dibujos-animados-astronauta-montando-cohete-concepto-icono-tecnologia-ciencia-aislado-vector-premium-estilo-dibujos-animados-plana_138676-3469.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero la imagen sigue cortada, me doy cuenta que solo es en la parte superior el corte, ya que el resto de la imagen se muestra bien en ambos casos. Llevo rato intentado solucionar esto, pero sigo sin encontrar una solucion.

Comment: @NikolaTesla Se que fue hace mucho de esto. Pero yo me encuentro con el mismo problema, al hacer zoom de la imagen, esta se corta. Sólo quería saber si lo pudiste solucionar.